"Equivariance" (?) of Adjoint action on $\mathfrak{g}$ and a $G \times V \rightarrow V$ action
I know the following theorem to be true (at least in some cases) but I don't know what this property is called or why it works.
Let $G$ be a Lie group acting on a vector space $V$. This induces a $\mathfrak{g}$ action on $V$ through differentiating. Then the following holds:
$$(\operatorname{Ad}_g \xi) \cdot v = g \cdot (\xi \cdot (g^{-1} \cdot v)) , \quad g \in G, \xi \in \mathfrak{g}, v \in V$$
On the LHS, $G$ is acting on $\mathfrak{g}$ first via the adjoint action $Ad_{g}\xi = g \xi g^{-1}$ to produce a new element of $\mathfrak{g}$ to act on $V$. On the RHS $\xi$ acts on $V$ directly and then the $G$ action on $V$ is applied to elements of $V$.
What is the name of this property? I suspect it is something important and applies to many situations where there are actions $G_1 \times X \rightarrow X, G_2 \times X \rightarrow X, G_1 \times G_2 \rightarrow G_2$ and certain axioms hold more general than Lie groups and vectors spaces.
Example of $SO(3), V = \mathbb{R}^3$. $\xi \in \mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{o}(3) \simeq \mathbb{R}^3$ acting via the cross product. We also have $\operatorname{Ad}_{O}\xi := O \xi$
Then $(\operatorname{Ad}_O \xi) v = O\xi \times v = O(\xi \times O^{-1}v ) = O \cdot (\xi \cdot O^{-1}v)$ which is as hypothesised.

How does $G$ act on $V$ from both sides? An action of $G$ on a vector space $V$ means that it acts on one side (typically left)

I assume there exists both left and right actions. (i.e. if it was a matrix Lie group, then the obvious way)

Actually, after doing some examples this is an unnecessary assumption (also a typo spotted in the initial formulation). Allow me a moment to edit the question to be more helpful.

Rather than equivariance of the adjoint representation, I think this is simply equivariance of the Lie algebra's representation.
If $\rho:G\to\operatorname{GL}(V)$ is a Lie group representation with induced Lie algebra representation $d\rho:\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{gl}(V)$. Then what you are saying is that: $$d\rho(\operatorname{Ad}_g(X)) = \operatorname{Ad}_{\rho(g)}(d\rho(X))$$
That is to say $d\rho \circ \operatorname{Ad}_g = \operatorname{Ad}_{\rho(g)} \circ\ d\rho$ so $d\rho$ is equivariant with respect to the adjoint representation on $\mathfrak{g}$ and the induced representation of $G$ on $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ ($g \mapsto \operatorname{Ad}_{\rho(g)}$).
Proving this is true is not too hard. For ease, we can use the exponential map together with the following results: $d\rho(X) = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\rho(\exp(tX))$ and $\exp(\operatorname{Ad}_g(X))=g\exp(X)g^{-1}$.
Then $$\begin{align}d\rho(\operatorname{Ad}_g(X)) &= \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\rho(\exp(t\operatorname{Ad}_g(X))) \\ &= \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\rho(g\exp(tX)g^{-1}) \\ &= \rho(g)\left(\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\rho(\exp(tX))\right)\rho(g^{-1}) \\&= \rho(g) d\rho(X) \rho(g^{-1}) \\&= \operatorname{Ad}_{\rho(g)}(d\rho(X)) \end{align} $$
I'm not sure this extends more generally as it is really a result about the link between $\rho$ and $d\rho$.

This is precisely what I was trying to articulate. Thank you.
